# Fitted values from the ivreg {AER} object do not match manual 2SLS results

Tags: r, linear-regression, prediction, lm

I'm trying to find out why fitted values from the ivreg estimation {AER} differ from manually performed 2-stage least squares (and from the appropriate reduced form equation)... the help for ivreg and ivreg.fit states that it invokes lm() repeatedly. I provide example from the {AER} package with fitted values calculated.

```
rm(list = ls())
require('AER') # install.packages('AER')
## data and example adapted from the AER package
data("CigarettesSW")
CigarettesSW$rprice <- with(CigarettesSW, price/cpi)
CigarettesSW$rincome <- with(CigarettesSW, income/population/cpi)
CigarettesSW$tdiff <- with(CigarettesSW, (taxs - tax)/cpi)

## Estimation by IV: log(rprice) is endogenous, tdiff is IV for log(rprice):
fm <- ivreg(log(packs) ~ log(rprice) + log(rincome) | log(rincome) + tdiff,
            data = CigarettesSW)
## 
##
# Reduced form for log(rprice)
rf.rprice <- lm(log(rprice) ~ log(rincome) + tdiff,
                data = CigarettesSW)
# Reduced form for log(packs)
rf.lpacks <- lm(log(packs) ~ log(rincome) + tdiff,
                data = CigarettesSW)
# "Manual" 2SLS estimation of the "fm" equation
m2sls <- lm(log(packs) ~ rf.rprice$fitted.values + log(rincome),
            data = CigarettesSW)
# Coefficients of "m2sls" are matched to "fm" object:
summary(m2sls)
summary(fm)
#
# It is my understanding, that fitted values from ivreg-fitted object "fm",
# manually performed 2SLS (in "m2sls") and from the reduced form rf.lpacks
# should be the same:
#
head(fm$fitted.values, 10)
head(m2sls$fitted.values, 10)
head(rf.lpacks$fitted.values, 10)
#
# However, fitted values from ivreg are different.
```

Most probably, I'm missing something obvious, but I'm stuck anyway. Would greatly appreciate any comments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `predict()` and the `fitted()` methods for `ivreg` objects simply compute `x %*% b` where `x` is the original regressor matrix and `b` is the vector of coefficients (estimated by IV). Thus:

```
x <- model.matrix(~ log(rprice) + log(rincome), data = CigarettesSW)
b <- coef(m2sls)
```

And then the fitted values from your manual computation are:

```
head(drop(x %*% b))
##        1        2        3        4        5        6 
## 4.750353 4.751864 4.720216 4.778866 4.919258 4.596331
```

which exactly matches the computations from `ivreg`:

```
head(fitted(fm))
##        1        2        3        4        5        6 
## 4.750353 4.751864 4.720216 4.778866 4.919258 4.596331
```

Comment: Thank you! This explanation is - technically - exactly what I was looking for. Yet, the ivreg-estimated coefficients in "fm" equation and in the manual 2sls "m2sls" are identical. Therefore I assume ivreg must use the fitted values from the first stage (reduced form) in the 2nd stage estimation. Yet, those fitted values are ignored for prediction. So, to rephrase my question: are the ivreg fitted values correct ?

Comment: The two regressions you conduct correspond to what `ivreg` carries out for estimating the regression coefficients. But the important point is that these auxiliary regressions are just "tricks" to obtain coefficient estimates for the _original_ untransformed/unprojected regressors! Hence, the original variables (in `x`) with the IV-estimated coefficients (in `b`) should be used for predictions.

Answer (score 1):

With ivreg, you have to include your other RHS variables both in front of the "|" and afterwards.

For example:

```
stage1<-predict(lm(endogenous.var~x1+x2+instrument,data=data))
data$stage1<-stage1
stage2<-lm(dependent~x1+x2+stage1,data=data)
```

does not give you the same coefficients as

```
iv.model<-ivreg(dependent~x1+x2+endogenous|instrument,data=data)
```

It will, however, give you the same answer as

```
iv.model<-ivreg(dependent~x1+x2+endogenous|instrument+x1+x2,data=data.
```

Live example:

```
rm(list=ls())

library(AER)
data(mtcars)

#let cyl be an instrument for hp
stage1<-predict(lm(hp~cyl+disp,data=mtcars))

mtcars$stage1<-stage1

stage2<-lm(mpg~stage1+disp,data=mtcars)

#this is not the same as 
ivreg.bad<-ivreg(mpg~hp|cyl+disp,data=mtcars)

#and this doesn't even work
ivreg.bad2<-ivreg(mpg~disp+hp|cyl,data=mtcars)

#but it is the same as 
ivreg.good<-ivreg(mpg~disp+hp|cyl+disp,data=mtcars)

summary(stage2)
summary(ivreg.good)
summary(ivreg.bad)
```

Note of course this just refers to the coefficients.  The standard errors will be different as ivreg automatically applies the appropriate adjustment.

Comment: I believe disp is the control variable and cyl is the IV for hp. So in ivreg shld be ivreg(mpg~hp+disp|disp+cyl, data=mtcars)? But the output is the same as ur ivreg.good though